# Failed backup after upgrade

Tags: backup

No backup since upgrade to 13.04.  I get: Giving up on request after 5 attempts, last status 400 Bad Request

Comment: We need a bit more information. What backup strategy are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Deja Dup.  Both automatic backup and manual give same message.

Comment: I just un-installed it.  Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you may have run across this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/deja-dup/+bug/1161599